# What is the command for converting number of BMP files in a folder to a video in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, recording

Can anyone help me in giving a proper command in ffmpeg to convert a set of [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) files which is getting generated in a folder to videos? But though the filenames are in a successive order it will not start from 1. I.e. if I start ffmpeg.exe like

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input%05d.bmp video.asf -vframe 30
```

it will take the filename from input00001 to 30 numbers only. But I want a code to take files with filenames as it is generated because according to my program my first files may get deleted and recording may be needed at some extend only, that is: it depends. That is if the folder is having filenames starting from input 00045 then it should take filename starting from that filename to next 30 frames.

Comment: is this question programming related ?

Comment: Yes, it is programming related.  He's trying to use ffmpeg in a program, so the CLI is basically an API in this context.